# Need for Fast map between string and integers

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map of string and unsigned, in which I store a word to its frequency of the following form:

```
map<string,unsigned> mapWordFrequency; //contains 1 billion such mappings
```

Then I read a huge file (100GB), and retain only those words in the file which have a frequency greater than 1000. I check for the frequency of the words in the file using: mapWordFrequency[word]>1000. However, it turns out as my mapWordFrequency has 1 billion mappings and my file is huge, therefore trying to check mapWordFrequency[word]>1000 for each and every word in the file is very slow and takes more than 2 days. Can someone please suggest as to how can I improve the efficiency of the above code.

map does not fit in my RAM and swapping is consuming a lot of time.

Would erasing all words having frequency < 1000 help using erase function of map?

Comment: You could try an `unordered_map` or [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  I'd suggest initially using say 1GB and if it's faster than `map`, then try the whole thing.  Also, use a profiler as it may not be the map lookup that's slow.  What's your peak/final `mapWordFrequency.size()`?  In other words - how many *unique* words are there?

Comment: You should probably use `hash_map` instead if available. It has `O(1)` complexity instead of `O(log N)` - it should matter if you have large number of elements. On the other hand you could build a radix-tree so you get `O(L)` performance, where `L` is the length of the word.

Comment: mapWordFrequency.size() is a billion

Comment: @TonyD Can you please give a little example with trie?

Comment: @RoseSharma Then `log2(N)` would be about 30 - the difference between `O(1)` and `O(log N)` would do good. In addition a hash-table does not require to do as many memory accesses (and with them cache-misses).

Comment: Are you sure your huge map fits into your RAM? If not swapping will be your first enemy.

Comment: If it doesn't fit into RAM you will have to select your solution more carefully.

Comment: @marom Yes, map does not fit in my RAM and swapping is consuming a lot of time

Comment: You need to process smaller chunks if you are swapping out. Almost anything is more efficient that that. I would consider farming this job out to several computers on smaller parts of the file. Or to different HDDs or a RAID setup.

Comment: @Galik Sounds efficient..how can I give the job to to different HDDs or a RAID setup

Comment: @marom Would erasing all words having frequency < 1000 help using erase function of map?

Comment: `cat file_with_100gb.txt | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr` is probably much faster than 2 days.

Comment: @RoseSharma If there are really 1 billion entries in the map and you have a document with an average word length of 5 characters you will need appr. 30 GB of memory (64bit) .  (key = 6 bytes (char*) + 8 bytes (length) + 8 bytes (capacity) + 4 bytes (refcount) = 26 bytes, value = 4 bytes). Could you even parse the file or is the value stated above wrong?

Comment: @RoseSharma It really depends on what *exactly* is making this process slow whether or not any of my suggestions would work. If you are swapping out then I would say you need to stop that first. Perhaps you could write intermediate results to a database whenever your hash map gets too large? That would be better than the performance degradation you'll get from the swap file. The idea of several HDDs might be of benefit if a lot of the task is IO bound. I just meant to cut your file up into smaller chunks and have your program read them from different physical devices.

Comment: How about using a database?

Comment: @Jens You would still have the problem that the process(es) uses more RAM than what is available.

Comment: @RoseSharma You could for example break down the work by simply splitting the input and run the work on separate computers (or processes using separate harddisks) and then merge the results. You don't even have to split the work by cutting the file midways, you could split the file by the first letter of each word (which will reduce the map size for each part smaller).

Comment: @SimonKraemer No. There are sorting algorithms which sort large files without reading them completely into memory. Sorting is a very old problem and RAM was very expensive and small in the old times. GNU sort uses an external sorting algorithm to do this: http://vkundeti.blogspot.de/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html

Comment: Could you give some more context of your problem? If it is part of a larger data processing, it may be worth to pre-process the data before using it, e.g. sorting it or creating a b-tree (or putting it into a database).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use an `unordered_map` as opposed to a `map`. As already discussed in the comments, the former will give you an insertion/retrieval time of `O(1)` as opposed to `O(logn)` in a `map`.

As you have already said, memory swapping is consuming a lot of time. So how about tackling the problem incrementally. Load the maximum data and `unordered_map` you can into memory, hash it, and continue. After one pass, you should have a lot of unordered_maps, and you can start to combine them in subsequent passes.

You could improve the speed by doing this in a distributed manner. Processing the pieces of data on different computers, and then combining data (which will be in form of unordered maps. However, I have no prior experience in distributed computing, and so can't help beyond this.

Also, if implementing something like this is too cumbersome, I suggest you use external mergesort. It is a method of sorting a file too large to fit into memory by sorting smaller chunks and combining them. The reason I'm suggesting this is that external mergesort is a pretty common technique, and you might find already implemented solutions for your need. Even though the time complexity of sorting is higher than your idea of using a `map`, it will reduce the overhead in swapping as compared to a map. As pointed out in the comments, `sort` in linux implements external mergesort.

Comment: Would erasing all words having frequency < 1000 help using erase function of map?

Comment: @RoseSharma : Since my suggestion is to incrementally build the hash table, you can't predict which word will have a frequency of less than a 1000, as its frequency counts will be distributed across multiple tables. Finding if frequency count across multiple tables is less than 1000 or not is equivalent to solving the problem itself.

Comment: @RoseSharma How would you delete those words if you can't identify them until after you've counted all of them?

Comment: Under linux, sort implements an external merge sort.

Comment: @Jens Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hash map where your hashed string will be key and occurrence will be value. It will be faster. You can choose a good string hashing based on your requirement. Here is link of some good hashing function:

http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx

you can use some third party libraries for this also.

EDIT:
pseudo code

```
int mapWordFrequency[MAX_SIZE] = {0} ;// if MAX_SIZE is large go with dynamic memory location
int someHashMethod(string input);

loop: currString in ListOfString
          int key = someHashMethod(currString);
          ++mapWordFrequency[key];
          if(mapWordFrequency[key] > 1000)
              doSomeThing();
```

Update:
As @Jens pointed out there can be cases when someHashMethod() will return same int (hash) for two different string. In that case we have to resolve collision and then lookup time will be more than constant. Also as input size is very large creating a single array of that size may not be possible. In that case we may use distributed computing concepts but actual lookup time will again go up as compare to single machine.

Comment: does hash map exists in C++11

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. I have seen cases where a hash map was actually slower than std::map, although the asymptotic performance is much better. In these cases, computing the hash function neglected the performance benefits completely. This is because the hash function has to process the complete string, while the comparator in std::map often needs to look at the first few characters only.

Comment: @RoseSharma you can create a standard int array of required sized.

Comment: @dream_machine Can you please explain a little more

Comment: @RoseSharma suppose you have a string "abcde". you use a hash function on this string which will return you a integer equivalent of this string. You will have a int array `int arr[MAX_SIZE]`. you will check as `arr[hash_return_of_string]` and do other operation as you do on array

Comment: @dream_machine Would erasing all words having frequency < 1000 help using erase function of map?

Comment: @dream_machine You could also use the standard c++ class unordered_map and skip all the manual error-prone stuff.

Comment: @dascandy I agree but some times i have noticed that choice of a good hash function based on nature of input can increase performance.

Comment: @dream_machine What stops you from using a good hash function with std::unordered_map?

Comment: Do you mean "pseudo code" instead of "sudo code" maybe?

Comment: @Boris sorry that was typo

Comment: @Jens yes we can use that.

Comment: @dream_machine Your pseudo code lacks an important point: How do handle collisions? To do this, you must first be able to detect them, so you have to store something in the array which you can compare to the new string.

Comment: @Jens I am already considering that. any non-zero count value for particular position is a collision.

Comment: @dream_machine How do you distinguish between a word that occurs more than one, and two strings where someHashMethod(s1) == someHashMethod(s2)? Or do you propose to create a perfect hash function for the input words first?

Comment: @Jens for string str, `mapWordFrequency[someHashMethod(str)]` will return you occurrence count.  and yes hash of two different string can  be same. We can use standard way to resolve collisions and same case can arise in c++ map too( i am not sure about it). In that case lookup will be greater that O(1) for my method.

Comment: @dream_machine This is why I am asking. Your pseudo-code does not show that and can give readers the impression that no collision-handling is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the statistical distribution of your words, it may be worth compressing each word before adding it to the map. As long as this is lossless compression you can recover the original words after filtering. The idea being you may be able to reduce the average word size (hence saving memory, and time comparing keys). Here's a simple compression/decompression procedure you could use:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp> 

inline std::string compress(const std::string& data)
{
    std::stringstream decompressed {data};
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> stream;
    stream.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
    stream.push(decompressed);
    std::stringstream compressed {};
    boost::iostreams::copy(stream, compressed);
    return compressed.str();
}

inline std::string decompress(const std::string& data)
{
    std::stringstream compressed {data};
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> stream;
    stream.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    stream.push(compressed);
    std::stringstream decompressed;
    boost::iostreams::copy(stream, decompressed);
    return decompressed.str();
}
```

In addition to using a `std::unordered_map` as other have suggested, you could also move any words that have already been seen more than 1000 times out of the map, and into a `std::unordered_set`. This would require also checking the set before the map, but you may see better hash performance by doing this. It may also be worth rehashing occasionally if you employ this strategy.

Comment: I would not expect single words to have a significant compression ratio.

Comment: @nwp Depends on the source of the words. If they are long DNA sequences for example there could be a significant compression ratio. Given the OP says there are ~1billion unique words, source is clearly not English text.

Comment: @Daniel: given 1 billion words, and total file size of 100GB, the average per word must be 100 bytes, and that's for all repetitions of the word, plus some portion of the words are expected to cross that 1000-repetition threshold, so they're likely not that long.  I think nwp's hunch is more likely right, but compression's still worth the mention and might help Rose or someone later....

Answer (score 1):

You need another approach to your problem, your data is too big to be processed all at once. 
For example you could split your file into multiple files, let's say the easiest would be to logically splitting them by letters.

```
100GB/24 letters = 4.17 GB
```

Now you'll have `24` files of `4.17GB` each. 
You know that the words in any of the files can not be part of any other file, this will help you, since you won't have to merge the results.
With a 4GB file, it now gets easier to work in ram.

`std::map` has a problem when you start using a lot of memory, since it fragments a lot. Try `std::unordered_map`, and if that's still not performing well, you may be able to load in memory the file and sort it. Counting occurrences will be then quite easy.

Assuming you have several duplicates, your `map` or `unordered_map` will have a significantly lower memory footprint.

Run your code in a loop, for each file, and append the results in another file.
You should be done quite quickly.

Comment: The distribution of letters is not uniform, so the computation should take in account the relative frequency of the most common ones. In any case, the notion that the work can be parallelised might be very useful.

Comment: that was an example, if you split it to multiple extra files, you'll be game. 
aa, ab, ac, ad, ae...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be the memory footprint, so we are looking for a solution that uses up little memory. A way to save memory is to use sorted `vector`s instead of a `map`. Now, `vector` has a lookup time with ~log(n) comparisons and an average insert time of n/2, which is bad. The upside is you have basically no memory overhead, the memory to be moved is small due to separation of data and you get sequential memory (cache-friendliness) which can easily outperform a `map`. The required memory would be 2 (wordcount) + 4 (index) + 1 (`\0`-char) + x (length of word) bytes per word. To achieve that we need to get rid of the `std::string`, because it is just too big in this case.

You can split your `map` into a `vector<char>` that saves the strings one after another separated by `\0`-characters, a `vector<unsigned int>` for the index and a `vector<short int>` for the word count. The code would look something like this (tested):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<char> strings;
std::vector<unsigned int> indexes;
std::vector<short int> wordcount;
const int countlimit = 1000;

void insertWord(const std::string &str) {
    //find the word
    auto stringfinder = [](unsigned int lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
        return &strings[lhs] < rhs;
    };
    auto index = lower_bound(begin(indexes), end(indexes), str, stringfinder);
    //increment counter
    if (index == end(indexes) || strcmp(&strings[*index], str.c_str())) { //unknown word
        wordcount.insert(begin(wordcount) + (index - begin(indexes)), 1);
        indexes.insert(index, strings.size());
        strings.insert(end(strings), str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size() + 1);
    }
    else { //known word
        auto &count = wordcount[index - begin(indexes)];
        if (count < countlimit) //prevent overflow
            count++;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream f("input.txt");
    std::string s;
    while (f >> s) { //not a good way to read in words
        insertWord(s);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); ++i) {
        if (wordcount[i] > countlimit) {
            std::cout << &strings[indexes[i]] << ": " << wordcount[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

This approach still saves all words in memory. According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average+english+word+length) the average word length in the English language is 5.1 characters. This gives you a total memory requirement of (5.1 + 7) * 1bn bytes = 12.1bn bytes = 12.1GB. Assuming you have a halfway modern computer with 16+GB of RAM you can fit it all into RAM.

If this fails (because you don't have English words and they don't fit in memory), the next approach would be memory mapped files. That way you can make `indexes` point to the memory mapped file instead of `strings`, so you can get rid of `strings`, but the access time would suffer.

If this fails due to low performance you should look into [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) which is very easy to apply to this case. It gives you as much performance as you have computers.

Answer (score 1):

> @TonyD Can you please give a little example with trie? –  Rose Sharma

Here's an example of a trie approach to this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <array>

class trie
{
  public:
    void insert(const std::string& s)
    {
        node_.insert(s.c_str());
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const trie& t)
    {
        return os << t.node_;
    }

  private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node() : freq_(0) { }
        uint16_t freq_;
        std::array<Node*, 26> next_letter_{};

        void insert(const char* p)
        {
            if (*p)
            {
                Node*& p_node = next_letter_[*p - 'a'];
                if (!p_node)
                    p_node = new Node;
                p_node->insert(++p);
            }
            else
                if (freq_ < std::numeric_limits<decltype(freq_)>::max()) ++freq_;
        }
    } node_;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& n)
    {
        os << '(';
        if (n.freq_) os << n.freq_ << ' ';
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
            if (n.next_letter_[i])
                os << char('a' + i) << *(n.next_letter_[i]);
        return os << ')';
    }
};

int main()
{
    trie my_trie;
    my_trie.insert("abc");
    my_trie.insert("abcd");
    my_trie.insert("abc");
    my_trie.insert("bc");
    std::cout << my_trie << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
(a(b(c(2 d(1 ))))b(c(1 )))
```

The output is a compressed/tree-like representation of your word-frequency histogram: `abc` appears `2` times, `abcd` `1`, `bc` `1`.  The parentheses can be thought of as pushing and popping characters from a "stack" to form the current prefix or - when there's a number - word.

Whether it improves much on a map depends on the variations in the input words, but it's worth a try.  A more memory efficient implementation might use a `vector` or `set` - or even a `string` of say space-separated- suffixes when there are few elements beneath the current prefix, then switch to the array-of-26-pointers when that's likely to need less memory.